# Getting the date of the last day of this [week/month/quarter/year]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is there any way to get the date (a `datetime`, `pd.Timestamp` or equivalent) of the last day of this [week/month/quarter/year] with `datetime`, `pandas` or other date & time utils?

Comment: Yes. Get today's `datetime` object and set the relevent field to its maximum

Comment: @unutbu, the `snap()` method could still work with some basic checks: if the snapped date is before the given date, move the given date forward by the given interval and snap again, then go back a day.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Yes, that could work, but I think it might be easier to use searchsorted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `datetime` only.

```
>>> d = datetime.date.today()
```

Last day of week:

```
# This was wrong earlier.
>>> d + datetime.timedelta(days=5 - d.weekday())
datetime.date(2015, 8, 15)
```

Last day of month:

```
>>> datetime.date(year=(d.year + int(d.month % 12 == 0)), month=(d.month + 1) % 12, day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
datetime.date(2015, 8, 31)
```

Last day of quarter:

```
>>> datetime.date(year=d.year, month=((d.month % 3) + 1) * 3 + 1, day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
datetime.date(2015, 9, 30)
```

Last day of year:

```
>>> datetime.date(year=d.year, month=12, day=31)
datetime.date(2015, 12, 31)
```

EDIT: This is all pretty ugly and using a higher level third party library is probably best, unless there is a compelling reason not to (and there does not seem to be here).

Comment: Nice! Maybe you want to shorted the code and improve the readability a bit using `from datetime import date, timedelta` and dropping the `datetime` namespace later on.

Comment: Minor mistake: `weekday` is in the range `0..6`. So you might return yesterday in the first example.

Comment: Thank you. Fixed. By dumb luck it worked for today. Although end of week  is ambiguous. I am assuming a US convention of Saturday.

Answer (score 5):

You could add a `pandas.DateOffset` to a `DateTimeIndex`, `Timestamp` or `datetime.date` or `datetime.datetime`:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2015-8-13', periods=4, freq='3D')
# DatetimeIndex(['2015-08-13', '2015-08-16', '2015-08-19', '2015-08-22'],
# dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='3D', tz=None)
```

Snap to the last day of the week (for example, Sunday):

```
In [232]: dates+offsets.Week(weekday=6)
Out[232]: DatetimeIndex(['2015-08-16', '2015-08-23', '2015-08-23', '2015-08-23'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None, tz=None)
```

Snap to the last day of the month:

```
In [207]: dates+offsets.MonthEnd()
Out[207]: DatetimeIndex(['2015-08-31', '2015-08-31', '2015-08-31', '2015-08-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None, tz=None)
```

Snap to the last day in the quarter:

```
In [212]: dates+offsets.QuarterEnd()
Out[215]: DatetimeIndex(['2015-09-30', '2015-09-30', '2015-09-30', '2015-09-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None, tz=None)
```

Snap to the last day of the year:

```
In [219]: dates+offsets.YearEnd()
Out[222]: DatetimeIndex(['2015-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None, tz=None)
```

Notice that adding an offset always advances the date. For example, 2015-08-16 is a Sunday, and adding an `offsets.Week(weekday=6)` advances it it 2015-08-23:

```
In [233]: pd.Timestamp('2015-8-16')+offsets.Week(weekday=6)
Out[233]: Timestamp('2015-08-23 00:00:00')
```

To prevent that from happening, you could subtract one day from `dates`:

```
In [234]: dates - offsets.Day() + offsets.Week(weekday=6)
Out[237]: DatetimeIndex(['2015-08-16', '2015-08-16', '2015-08-23', '2015-08-23'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None, tz=None)
```

Comment: The linked documentation says "nearest." Does it only snap forwards?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Thanks for the correction. Updated answer does "snap forward".

Answer (score 4):

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta, SU

def last_day_of_week(year, week_num):
    # assuming sunday is the last day of week
    # weeks= is an offset, hence the minus one
    return datetime.date(year, 1, 1) + relativedelta(weekday=SU(1), weeks=week_num - 1)

def last_day_of_month(year, month):
    return datetime.date(year, month, 1) + relativedelta(months=1, days=-1)

def last_day_of_year(year):
    return datetime.date(year, 1, 1) + relativedelta(years=1, days=-1)
```

Comment: I guess `last_day_of_year(N) == last_day_of_month(N, 12)` but you never know, maybe some day years will have 13 months…