# How to write a function which takes in the data as csv file and returns a standardised pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, data-science

201501 means the first week of 2015 and goes from 2014-12-29till 2015-01-04. How to get the last day of week from ISO 8601 week format

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Do any of these answer your question?: [Getting the date of the last day of this (week/month/quarter/year)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996872/getting-the-date-of-the-last-day-of-this-week-month-quarter-year), [Getting the last value for each week, with the matching date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577617/getting-the-last-value-for-each-week-with-the-matching-date), [Get the first day of the week for a Pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208570/get-the-first-day-of-the-week-for-a-pandas-series#:~:text=Get%20the%20first,Ask%20Question)

Comment: Quite a few other possibilities searching with `pandas last day of week site stackoverflow.com`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def myFunction(filePath):
    df = pd.read_csv(filePath)
    return df
```

Hope this helps, seems like you had two questions in one

Comment: Yes, I had two questions 1st one worked. About the second question, I have weeks in the format of ISO 8601-week number which starts from Monday close to 1st Jan. I have to extract the last day of the week from every week number and assign it to the respective week. Nothing seems to be working.